# mysql command for listing all the rows in a table?

Tags: mysql, command, subquery

**Relevant tables**

bookShop(shopNo, shopName, street, city, county)

orders(orderNo, sNo, oDate, salesRep)

I need to list all details of shops which have only one order

```
    SELECT shopNo, shopName, street, city, county
    FROM bookShop
    WHERE shopNo in (SELECT sNo
                     FROM  orders
                     WHERE (count(sNo))<1)
```

I know I can't use an aggregate function without using group by,but I feel that would be over complicating things would there be a simpler way of doing it ? Also , is there a my SQL command for listing all the details in the table instead of typing them all in  manually as I did above? Thanks

Comment: "I need to list all details of shops which have only **one** order" Your current query is wrong your query displays **NON existing** beause of the `count(sNo)) < 1` it should have been `count(sNo)) = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate in your subquery:

```
SELECT shopNo, shopName, street, city, county
FROM bookShop
WHERE shopNo in (SELECT sNo
                 FROM orders
                 GROUP BY sNo
                 HAVING COUNT(sNo) = 1);
```

Comment: "I need to list all details of shops which have only **one** order" it should have been `HAVING COUNT(sNo) = 1` instead.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're right, I missed that.  I guess I put too much faith in the OP's original query.

Comment: i didn't downvote by the way but really why is somebody downvoting for a simple operator error..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT *
    FROM bookShop
    WHERE shopNo in (SELECT sNo
                     FROM  orders
                     GROUP BY sNo
                     HAVING count(sNo)=1)
```

We use "*" to indicate all columns instead of specifying all column names.
We must use GROUP BY because you need a conditional value on a aggregate function "COUNT".

Edit: Added the actual condition the OP was asking.

Comment: Hi Sir @TimBiegeleisen , when I stated to answer, there was no answer and I too might have been writing the answer along with the first person and I might have answered without being congnizant of the another answer . According to you, should we delete the answer? If the SO doyens like you guide small people like me, I would be glad and delete the answer.

Comment: No worries +1.  This seems to happen a lot on the site.